# How can I better protect access to all site reports except 'Recent log messages' based on role?

Tags: users, log-messages

How can I better protect access to all site reports within `/admin/reports/` (except for *Recent log messages*)? I know I can hide it through CSS or disable the menu in management menu, but is there a better way to disable it?

I have these role defined (apart from Anonymous and Authenticated):

- System Developer (can view all reports).
- Admin (can only view 'Recent log messages').

Is there any Drupal function or hook that I can use to reach my goal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the permission for "Admin" to "access site reports" at

`Admin > People > Permissions`.

Add [hook_menu_alter](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_menu_alter/7) to a custom module, this part changes the access permission for the `admin/reports/dblog` menu path

```
/**
 * Implements hook_menu_alter
 */
function MYMODULE_menu_alter(&$items){
  // Allow access for administrator role to recent log entries
  // Use suitable permission here, e.g editorial "administer nodes"
  $items['admin/reports/dblog']['access arguments'] => array('administer nodes'), 
}
```

Clear menu cache, done.